# How to install plugin for MobaXterm?

Tags: windows, unix, plugins, remote-access, mobaxterm

I need a terminal that will support svn on windows and I found that [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) is one of them. However going to their [plugin installation page](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html) which says:

> To install these plugins, just download them and put them in the same directory than the MobaXterm executable.

So I downloaded it and put it in the file 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm Personal Edition however I still get the error message

```
Sorry: Svn is not included in this version of MobaXterm.

You can check online if you find a Svn plugin for MobaXterm
by ctrl+clicking here: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net .
If you need a custom version of MobaXterm that includes Svn,
do not hesitate to ask us for a quotation: mailto:contact@mobatek.net .
```

Does anyone have experience with this software or recommended a terminal that can support svn in windows?

Comment: Same problem, but with the Git plugin.  It just doesn't seem to do anything at all -- I put it in the same dir as the MobaXterm exec, restart Mobaterm, but no love.  Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: @Stabledog For GIT, I prefer to use `apt-get install git` in order to have the latest version. It is fully automatic (download and installation, no need to add plugin). What is also important it to update to last libopenssl version, so after the git install you need to update libopenssl with `apt-get install libopenssl100`. Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think there's any apt-get for MobaXterm.  That would be lovely, of course!

Comment: @Stabledog Well it certainly works for me, so I assume there is.

Answer (score 10):

You need to go into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm Personal Edition`  or whichever edition you have and place the plugin there. Restart `MobaXterm` and it should work.

Comment: I have a problem very similar to the OP -- only with the Git plugin.  I've put it in the MobaXterm Personal Edition folder, restart Mobaterm, but no love.   Typing 'git' yields no-such-command, and there's no git executable on the path.  Is there any troubleshooting tools for this stuff?

Answer (score 6):

I normally collect all the plugins which I require from http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/plugins.html

Once the *.mxt3 files are getting downloaded, I moved them to the installed folder where the MobaXterm_*.exe is there.

After restarting MobaXterm, this will work like a champ.

Hope if this solves your issue faster.

Answer (score 4):

1. Start MobaXterm terminal.
2. Type `MobApt` or `apt-get`. This will open **MobApt package manager**.

[image: MobApt package manager]

3. Once in the package manager, you have a variety of tools/commands that you can install by simply selecting and pressing `Install/Update`.

[image: MobaXterm MobApt package manager]

Answer (score 3):

i know the question is old. but you should put the plugin into your home.

if you check the setting you see this is the home directory

```
%CurrentDrive%:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\MobaXterm\home
```

witch is :

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\MobaXterm\home -- or whatever drive that u installed windows
```

i just installed the python plugin and it works fine

Answer (score 3):

In Mobaxterm simply type  :  `apt-get install subversion`

Usable just right after installation. No need to restart.

Same for git.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the name of the .mxt3 file (that you downloaded) to .zip
2. Extract the files, get the .exe files you want from the bin folder
   from the files you just extracted, and add them to the slash/bin
   folder of the Mobaxterm (where there are more .exe files)
3. Restart

Answer (score 2):

In order to finish your plugin installation, you need to restart MobaXterm. After restarting, type "svn" in the terminal and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try run the command:

#unalias svn

Answer (score 1):

When I saw $PATH and looked into its directories, there was no git.exe.

I downloaded git.mxt3 and put in program files (86) folder and restarted mobaterm.

After restart I can see a file named git.exe in my /bin folder. I am using Win7 (64 bit) and mobaXterm personal Edition v7.1 installed using windows installer (not portable )

Answer (score 0):

MobaXterm already has a 'Packages' button where you can search for plugins and download them. You don't need to go to github and other places to find the necessary files. Just using the built-in search feature under the 'Packages' option at the top of MobaXterm.